# Adding to character sequences in a .txt file that match identical sequences in another .txt file the name of the second file

Tags: r, txt

I am trying to edit using r a text file (A) so that any character sequences contained in it that match a list of words in another text file (B) are altered.
The matches should be modified to add at the end of every one of them the title of text file B.

I think I could use the readLines, writeLines and gsub functions in a way similar to this:

- `tx  <- readLines("~/Desktop/A.txt")`
- `tx2  <- gsub(pattern = "abc", replace = "def", x = tx)`
- `writeLines(tx2, con="~/Desktop/A2.txt")`

But for the pattern, instead of using "abc" I should use ANY of the objects in the data frame:

- `df<-read.table(file="B.txt", header=FALSE, sep="\n")`

And for the replace section I maybe could use the file_path_sans_ext function in the tools package:

- `tools::file_path_sans_ext("B.txt")`

I would just need instead of replacing the whole sequence of characters to add that section after it.

I honestly don't quite know how to cobble all of this together in a way that works. If you need any additional details please ask.